# Neo4j Casual Clustering benfits over High-Availability Clustering

Tags: neo4j

We are in the process of migrating HA cluster to Causal Clustering.

**Is there any real advantage of migrating from HA Clustering to Causal Clustering?**

Currently using REST End points only.

**Is it possible to have causal clustering with just two Neo4j instances?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Causal cluster is the new generation of Neo4j cluster, and it will continue to evolve with new releases.

There are many advantages for CC comparing to HA :

- no branch data (thanks to raft and consensus commit)
- more stability
- smart driver with bolt protocol (with LB and `read your own write` functionnality)
- cluster communication encryption
- ...

You need at minima *3 core nodes* to create a cluster (`2n+1` in fact where `n` is the number of failure you want to support).

I really recommend you to use the bolt protocol instead of the REST API, because official drivers only use bolt, and they can hide to you the complexity of a cluster.

Comment: With HA mode, we have not seen any significant improvement using BOLT.

Comment: Perhaps, but in term of functionalities on the driver side, it's completely different. So you will have a big gain in flexibility, and code. And FYI, there is no more arbiter node in CC. A cluster is formed at minima of 3 nodes ! (Perhaps that's why you have some trouble with your HA.)

Answer (score 0):

HA Clustering is deprecated in `Neo4j 3.5` and will be removed in `Neo4j 4.0`.

> The functionality described in this section (HA Clustering) has been deprecated and
>   will be removed in Neo4j 4.0. Causal Clustering should be used
>   instead.
>
> Source: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/ha-cluster/architecture/

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/

> Neo4j (Enterprise Only) Causal Clustering provides three main
>   features:
>
> **Safety:** Core Servers provide a fault tolerant platform for transaction processing which will remain available while a simple
>   majority of those Core Servers are functioning.
>
> **Scale:** Read Replicas provide a massively scalable platform for graph queries that enables very large graph workloads to be executed
>   in a widely distributed topology.
>
> **Causal consistency:** when invoked, a client application is guaranteed to read at least its own writes. Together, this allows the
>   end-user system to be fully functional and both read and write to the
>   database in the event of multiple hardware and network failures and
>   makes reasoning about database interactions straightforward.
>
> Source: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/introduction/

Comment: Building and Using a Neo4j 3.2 Causal Cluster — Alistair Jones, Neo4j: https://youtu.be/uCkPAQxSqLA

Answer (score -1):

To me, 3 CORE instances is the minimun
Then 3 ReadReplicas seems a minimum.

If you already have HA working, can you precise why moving to causal clustering ?

Comment: We are seeing some issue with HA fault tolerance and having only two neo4j instances with an arbiter.

Comment: As @logisima wrote, three is a minimum. CC is the new norm. 
Try adding a server to your cluster.